# Why does SendMessageAsync sporatically Perform Bad

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azureservicebus

I have a .NET web api deployed to Azure. I have a singleton service registered that acts as a message publisher. I also have the `ServiceBusClient` and the `ServiceBusAdministrationClient` registered as a singleton. We randomly started seeing performance issues and I've been able to identify 1 piece of the bottle neck is from the `await sender.SendMessageAsync(message)` line. It will take milliseconds to run then let's say a couple out of 10 times will take upwards of 10+ seconds.

```
    public async Task PublishMessageAsync<T>(T entity, bool isQueue = false)
    {
        var queueOrTopicName = "{my topic name}";

        try
        {
            if (ConnectionIsClosed())
                OpenClient();

            if (_client == null)
                return;

            if (!await _serviceBusAdministrator.MessageNamespaceExists(queueOrTopicName, isQueue))
                throw new Exception($"Unable to create message namespace for {queueOrTopicName}!");

            var serializedBody = JsonSerializer.Serialize(entity);
            var message = new ServiceBusMessage(serializedBody);

            // Implemented this to re-use senders hoping to help
            ServiceBusSender sender = null;
            if (_senders.ContainsKey(queueOrTopicName))
            {
                sender = _senders[queueOrTopicName];
            }
            else
            {
                sender = _client.CreateSender(queueOrTopicName);
                _senders.Add(queueOrTopicName, sender);
            }

            // This is what's sporatically taking forever
            await sender.SendMessageAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(ex, $"Timeout exception raised when publishing to {queueOrTopicName}. Detail: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

Using this version of the service bus package

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.11.1" />
```

What's even more strange is in our app insights, it seems that the "Receive" call of the service bus is taking forever too. I'm not sure if that's related or not, but it's definitely strange and I can't seem to pinpoint what else to look at. We are using the standard tier, but don't have the volume that would lead me to believe that's the problem If anybody could lend a hand and help point me in the right direction, it'd be GREATLY appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Service Bus is an AMQP-based service which uses a persistent stateful connection.  When you call `SendMessageAsync`, the client first needs to ensure that the connection has been established and is healthy.  Connections will timeout if idle for more than 60 seconds and may be force-closed by the service or interrupted by transient network issues, causing them to need to be recreated.

The client also retries failures implicitly, where multiple attempts for a network operation can take place during a single `SendMessageAsync` call.

In your scenario, the most likely cause is one of these.  If you're interested in understanding the exact reasons, I'd suggest [capturing SDK logs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/core/Azure.Core/samples/Diagnostics.md#logging).  Specifically, you'll be looking for:

***Event Source: Azure-Messaging-ServiceBus***

- Any warnings
- Any errors
- Send Message Start (Id: 1)
- Send Message Complete (Id: 2)
- Send Message Error (Id: 3)
- Create Send Link Start (Id: 80)
- Create Send Link Complete (Id: 81)
- Create Send Link Error (Id: 82)
- Send Link Closed (Id: 100)

Comment: Thanks for the reference @Jesse. I'll implement this package. I have a hunch that it could be connection throttling related possibly.

Comment: I don't believe it would be throttles - that's not a retriable error and you'd see exceptions surface from the `SendMessageAsync` call in that case.